# Dynamodb: compare two table values in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have below 2 table in dyanmodb

users1

| ID | name | rollno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First-4 | First | 4 |
| Second-2 | Second | 2 |

users2

| ID | name | rollno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First-4 | First | 4 |
| Fourth-2 | Fourth | 2 |

so if we compare users1 and users2 we should get the values which are present in both table
so it will return

| ID | name | rollno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First-4 | First | 4 |

In dyamodb How can I achieve it using node js sdk lambda.

Comment: You will get the result one time or every day? Get all items in 2 tables and compare them.

Comment: one time I need to get it in an efficient way

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not support joins, so you're going to need to do a lot of the heavy lifting yourself if you want to compute the difference between two DynamoDB tables.  You're going to have to manually compare the items of each table, probably by using the `scan` operation on each table.

Alternatively, you might consider [exporting the entire database to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.html) and doing the comparison outside of DDB.

If this is a one-time thing, performance may not be much of a concern.  If this is a common access pattern in your database, you'll want to take an entirely different approach.